# Getting datetime from mysql into php?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have the following code (a countdown timer using php and javascript) that I am working on. What I am trying to do is to get the datetime `($end_date)` from the mysql and place it in the `$date =''` inside my code.

This code will work just fine if i enter the date and time manually in the code like this: `$date = 'September 17 2013 12:00:00 PM GMT';`

but i need it to work some how like this:

```
$date = echo $dynamicList;
```

or like this maybe:

```
$date = echo $end_date;
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong!

here is my full code:

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
?>
<?php date_default_timezone_set('GMT'); ?>
<?php
session_start();
// Run a select query to get my letest 6 items
// Connect to the MySQL database  
include "config/connect.php";
$dynamicList = "";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM item ORDER BY id";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
$productCount = mysqli_num_rows($query); // count the output amount
if ($productCount > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ 
             $id = $row["id"];
             $product_name = $row["product_name"];
             $date_added = strftime("Y-m-d", strtotime($row["date_added"]));
             $end_date = strftime("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($row["end_date"]));
             $price = $row["price"];
             $dynamicList .= '<div>' . $end_date . '
      </div>';
    }
} else {
    $dynamicList = "No Records";
}
?>

<?php
$date = echo $dynamicList;
$exp_date = strtotime($date);
$now = time();

if ($now < $exp_date) {
?>
<script>
// Count down milliseconds = server_end - server_now = client_end - client_now
var server_end = <?php echo $exp_date; ?> * 1000;
var server_now = <?php echo time(); ?> * 1000;
var client_now = new Date().getTime();
var end = server_end - server_now + client_now; // this is the real end time

var _second = 1000;
var _minute = _second * 60;
var _hour = _minute * 60;
var _day = _hour *24
var timer;

function showRemaining()
{
    var now = new Date();
    var distance = end - now;
    if (distance < 0 ) {
       clearInterval( timer );
       document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = 'EXPIRED!';

       return;
    }
    var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
    var hours = Math.floor( (distance % _day ) / _hour );
    var minutes = Math.floor( (distance % _hour) / _minute );
    var seconds = Math.floor( (distance % _minute) / _second );

    var countdown = document.getElementById('countdown');
    countdown.innerHTML = '';
    if (days) {
        countdown.innerHTML += 'Days: ' + days + '<br />';
    }
    countdown.innerHTML += 'Hours: ' + hours+ '<br />';
    countdown.innerHTML += 'Minutes: ' + minutes+ '<br />';
    countdown.innerHTML += 'Seconds: ' + seconds+ '<br />';
}

timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
</script>
<?php
} else {
    echo "Times Up";
}
?>
<div id="countdown"></div>
```

could someone please help me out with this?

I do not get any errors on my page. only a blank page and if I change  `$date = echo $dynamicList;` to `$date = '$dynamicList';` i get the Times Up message!

any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT My new code:**

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
?>
<?php date_default_timezone_set('GMT'); ?>
<?php
session_start();
// Run a select query to get my letest 6 items
// Connect to the MySQL database  
include "config/connect.php";
$dynamicList = "";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM item ORDER BY id";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
$productCount = mysqli_num_rows($query); // count the output amount
if ($productCount > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ 
             $id = $row["id"];
             $product_name = $row["product_name"];
             $date_added = strftime("%Y-%m-%d", strtotime($row["date_added"]));
             $end_date = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", strtotime($row["end_date"]));
             $price = $row["price"];
             $dynamicList .= '<div>' . $end_date . '
      </div>';
    }
} else {
    $dynamicList = "No Records";
}
?>

<?php
$date = "'".$end_date."'";
$exp_date = strtotime($date);
$now = time();

if ($now < $exp_date) {
?>
<script>
// Count down milliseconds = server_end - server_now = client_end - client_now
var server_end = <?php echo $exp_date; ?> * 1000;
var server_now = <?php echo time(); ?> * 1000;
var client_now = new Date().getTime();
var end = server_end - server_now + client_now; // this is the real end time

var _second = 1000;
var _minute = _second * 60;
var _hour = _minute * 60;
var _day = _hour *24
var timer;

function showRemaining()
{
    var now = new Date();
    var distance = end - now;
    if (distance < 0 ) {
       clearInterval( timer );
       document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = 'EXPIRED!';

       return;
    }
    var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
    var hours = Math.floor( (distance % _day ) / _hour );
    var minutes = Math.floor( (distance % _hour) / _minute );
    var seconds = Math.floor( (distance % _minute) / _second );

    var countdown = document.getElementById('countdown');
    countdown.innerHTML = '';
    if (days) {
        countdown.innerHTML += 'Days: ' + days + '<br />';
    }
    countdown.innerHTML += 'Hours: ' + hours+ '<br />';
    countdown.innerHTML += 'Minutes: ' + minutes+ '<br />';
    countdown.innerHTML += 'Seconds: ' + seconds+ '<br />';
}

timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
</script>
<?php
} else {
    echo "Times Up";
}
?>
<div id="countdown"></div>
```

Comment: `echo $date = $dynamicList;`

Comment: @Richie, this will only echo `Y-m-d H:i:s` on the page. absolutely wrong

Comment: you are storing html tags in your `$dynamicList` variable and then `strtotime($data)`. thas not the correct way to store and change in timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change these lines:

```
$date = echo $dynamicList;
```

With the following code:

```
$date = "'".$end_date."'";
```

And define the `$end_date` as a global variable.

And also add the some more parameter in the following for timezone:

```
$end_date = strftime("Y-m-d H:i:s A T", strtotime($row["end_date"]));
                                 ^^^ add these
```

You are getting the timesup message because of your if condition is not correct:

```
if ($now < $exp_date) {
```

As you are comparing the unixtimestap with the timeformat.

Use this code:

```
$date = "'".$end_date."'";
$exp_date = strtotime($date);
$now = strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s A T"));
```

Then compare these time. You need to change the $now also.

Comment: Also, note that the user is using strftime.  To use the date format they gave, switch `strftime` to `date` or change the time format to `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %p %Z`

Comment: nope, still i get Times Up message! the `$end_date` is set for the next 5 days in mysql as well. but i still get Times Up message.

Comment: I have edited my question with my new code. still doesn't work though.

Comment: Sorry but I am still getting the same Times Up message on the page! nothing seem to work.

Comment: @EnergyLynxEnergyLynx check the code by echoing the value of both variables: $now and $end_date.

Comment: okay, I did `<?php echo $end_date; ?>` in the code and I get this echo-ed on the page: `Y-m-d H:i:s A T`

Comment: and if i change the format to `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %p %Z` i get the end date echo-ed correctly on the page like this: `2013-09-27 06:00:00 AM GMT`

Comment: I already have changed the format to `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %p %Z` but i still get the Times Up message! what other formats do i have to change?

Comment: @EnergyLynxEnergyLynx instead of `strftime` use the date function.

Comment: if i do that, it means i have to change the entire javascript code as well which i really don't want to do that. i rather make what I have work. I think if i could get the month name instead of number then i might be onto something. I just don't know how to get the month name.

Comment: Okay now I have changed to date function and I've managed to get the month's name echo-ed on the page. basically I formatted it correctly like so: `September 27 2013 06:00:00 AM GMT` but I still get the Times Up message! any ideas?

Comment: I've made it work by removing ."'" around the $end_date mate.